# adding records, editing deleting

Tags: winforms, grid, syncfusion

Can anyone give me what events to handle for syncfusion grid control. 
In the context menu, if add record is chosen the the user must be able to add and then save it in the db

thanks
sun

Answer (score 0):

If it is the ContextMenuStrip through which you bounded the context menu to the grid, you can handle the ItemClicked event of it and handle updates to the bounded data source. GridGroupingControl, by default, reflects the changes made in the underlying datasource provided the datasource supports notification on any changes(like IBindingList, IEnumerable, etc.,).

The following code illustrates this considering the bounded datasource as DataView.

```
// Event Handler
this.gridGroupingControl1.ContextMenuStrip.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(ContextMenuStrip_ItemClicked);

// Method Invoked
void ContextMenuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt = (this.gridGroupingControl1.DataSource as DataView).Table;
   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
      dr[i] = 0; //default value
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

For datasource types(like ArrayList), that don't raise notification on its own for any change on it, once the update to the underlying datasource have been handled, the following code can be handled to refresh the GridGroupingControl inorder to reflect the updated view.

```
this.gridGroupingControl1.Reinitialize();
```